# Is there a way to get text input in Javascript/Html without a text box?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a custom terminal as a website with custom commands but I am struggling to get text input without using a text box. I tried this:

```
<input type='text' id='textInput'>
```

but it creates a text box.
I also tried using an event listener as such:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>{
        if(event.keyCode == 65 ) {
            msg += 'a';
        }
});
```

but it does not work as it gives an error:
**ReferenceError: document is not defined**

and even if it did it would be slow to do that for every key.

Comment: pardon my naivety but could the use of a text box or text area that is styled with css suffice

Comment: unsure how the document is not defined.... How are you adding this to the page? What browser?

Comment: @KevinCrum I am very bad with css so if you could please show me an example it would be very helpful thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key `document.addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>{ console.log(event.key) });`

Comment: @epascarello I followed it now it gives me this error: ReferenceError: addEventListener is not defined

Comment: Again.... How are you adding this to the page? What browser? –

Comment: Sorry, I am very dumb so I apologize. I have written the keyboard input code in the backend, not the frontend. kill me

Comment: @2F33T - what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let txt = document.getElementById('textInput')
txt.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        if(event.keyCode == 65 ) {
            msg += 'a';
        }
});
```

And if you don't like the feel/look of your text input with the box, you can always edit it yourself with CSS

You can do something like this:

```css
<style>
    #bg{
        background-color: black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #textInput{
        color: green; #Change to a color you like
        border: None;
        outline: None;
        line-height: 25px;
        font-family: monospace; #You can also change
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 100%;
</style>
```

```html
<div id='bg'>
    <input type='text' id='textInput' >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to input data but do not want to display the textbox, then I suggest setting the CSS on the textbox to `opacity: 0;` - example:

```
<input style="opacity: 0;" id="textInput" />

<script>
document.getElementById('textInput').focus(); // focus on the element
document.getElementById('textInput').addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        if(event.keyCode == 65 ) {
            msg += 'a';
        }
});
</script>
```

EDIT: Updated answer to use `opacity` instead of `display` in CSS

Comment: You cannot focus an input which is `display: none`

Comment: @blex Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but the OP's second code example is simpler, since it does not require an input and works fine

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the outline of a textbox? If so, try setting its value to 0px:

```html
<input type="text" style="border: 0px none;" />
```

Also give a try to get input directly from prompt box:

```html
<button onclick="promptValue()">Try it</button>

<p id="enteredValue"></p>

<script>
function promptValue() {
  var textValue = prompt("Please enter a value");
  document.getElementById("enteredValue").innerHTML = textValue;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few syntax fixes which might help:

1. **Use `window` instead of `document`** for the `addEventListener`. `document` probably should be use if you are calling for something to happen to one specific item. (e.g. `document.querySelector('#searchbox')`.)
2. Using `keydown` might be more effective than `keyup` for keyboard commands.
3. Use strict equality (`===`) instead of classic equality (`==`).
4. `keyCode` is deprecated. Use `key` instead. It will also be easier to code. (Note: if you need to use capital A, consider using `event.key === 'A' && event.shiftKey`.)

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if(event.key === 'A' ) {
            msg += 'a';
        }
});
```